# change Express generated app.js file to server.js

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack

I am using the command `express -e myAppName` to start up my app.

By default this gives me a file named `app.js` which as you all know holds all my server logic, middleware, etc.

I tried changing the name of `app.js` to `server.js` and after doing so I got this error. `Error: Cannot find module '../app'`

So I go into my bin directory and inside the `www` file I change `var app = require('../app');` to `var app = require('../server');` however that did not fix the error so it persisted.

I am relatively new to web development (3 months) and almost 2 months working with the MEAN stack. I looked around for a while and didn't find anyone attempting to change the file names like I want.

Comment: what command are you using to start your application?

Comment: Sorry If I don't understand your question.. I start the app running mongod, nodemon and I am on localhost 3000 atm.. Is that what you mean?

Comment: nodemon is what I was after. I was wondering if you used npm start in which case you might have to change your package.json. I don't normally generate express apps but I will try to reproduce now.

Comment: I did not think about that.. You might be right. I will try to take a look. Thank you!

Comment: @chriskelly It worked! You were right. It looks like it was 3 steps...

1. change the file name like I did to server.js

2. replace `var app = require('../app'); to var app = require('../server');` insde the www file

3. add this in my package.Json `"main": "server.js",`

I am very happy haha. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you did is correct (i.e. updating the path in bin\www).

However, you should start your express app using `npm start`

In general, npm apps allow you to specify a command inside package json which will start your application and this is the first place to look.

For an express generated this should look like the following:

```
{
  "scripts" : {
    "start" : "node bin/www"
  }
}
```

If you want to change it and pass arguments later all you have to do is update your *package.json* file and your end users will not be affected.

`npm start` gives users of your program a **consistent way to start the application** regardless of what filenames or parameters you change

## setup for development

In your case, since you are using nodemon to automatically restart while you develop, you should use it as follows:

```
nodemon bin/www
```

instead of modify your entry point you should make a special script like this:

```
{
  "scripts" : {
    "start" : "node bin/www",
    "devel" : "nodemon bin/www"
  }
}
```

Then to start nodemon use:

```
npm run devel
```

This way your end user does not start with the nodemon development tool.

Comment: I do remember my instructor making a reference or suggesting nodemon bin/www I have to go back and look at my notes. There's so much to grasp and now that I am done with school I am trying to set up a consistent and practical way that works for me to get up and running in making new apps. Thank again. I will do more reading on this.

Comment: @Shotbyabel: No problem. I'll update for how you should handle nodemon! don't forget to accept answer when you get 15 points ;)

Comment: That's really kind of you. You got it! I just did.. My first one! This was buggin me for a while. Now I can tell others how it can be done. Have a good night.